# No logro mostrar toda la Información en PHP

Tags: php

Les explico quiero mostrar los títulos de unos post, ahorita solo esto haciendo pruebas para luego implementar luego.

```
<?php

include '../AvisionV2/db/db.php';

$query_sql = "SELECT
                pos.i_titulo AS Titulo,
                pos.i_descripcion AS Descripcion,
                pro.p_producto AS Producto,
                usu.r_usuario AS Usuario
                FROM
                tb_post pos
                INNER JOIN tb_publicacion pub ON
                pos.id_publicacion = pub.id_publicacion
                INNER JOIN tb_producto pro ON
                pub.id_producto = pro.id_producto
                INNER JOIN tb_usuario usu ON
                pub.id_usuario = usu.id_usuario";

if ($resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_sql)) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($row);

      $titulo = $row["Titulo"];
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>

 <body>
 <p>Titulo</p>
 <h5> <?php echo $titulo;  ?> </h5>
 </body>

 </html>
```

con el `print_r($row);` logro mostrar los post

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando yo lo paso en el HTML 
solo me muestra la ultima entrada

Que seria Titulo 4

lo que quiero lograr que en el

```
<h5> <?php echo $titulo;  ?> </h5>
```

dentro el de `<h5>` Me muestre Titulo 1 , Titulo 2 etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven solo me muestra Titulo 4 y no como Titulo 1, Titulo 2 ....

Espero su ayuda o su asesoría para mejorar.

Comment: Si previamente has inicializado la variable `$titulo`, en el bucle debes reemplazar `$titulo = $row["Titulo"];` por `$titulo .= $row["Titulo"];`. Esto solucionará el problema que estás planteando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Puntualmente no veo la necesidad de fragmentar tanto el código, es decir que una variable sola almacene el *string* de la consulta y luego por separado pases esa variable a la función que ejecutará dicha consulta
- Otro punto que me parece un tanto extraño en su estructura es como *comparas* e inicializas el bucle, ya que si lo que tratas es de verificar el estado de la consulta; considero que es mejor [manejar los errores por medio de las funciones de mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php)
- Solo te otorga el último valor por que cuando igualas a **`$titulo`** con lo que obtienes **`$row["Titulo"]`** y lo imprimes por fuera, este tomará el último valor que obtuvo el bucle, en consecuencia solo te retorna un título.
- Dentro del bucle al hacer **`print_r($row);`** te muestra todos, por que el bucle imprimirá cada valor leido por cada iteración que haga hasta terminar la lectura
- Por lo anterior propongo que tu estructura de PHP quede dentro del HTML, para que sea dentro del mismo ciclo que imprimas todos los títulos disponibles de este modo:
- Dentro del propio bucle cuando estas imprimiendo lo que la variabale **`$renglon`** retorna del índice **`Titulo`** le puedes concatenar etiquetas HTML por ejemplo un párrafo para comenzar a darle estilos a la información que planeas mostrar

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        //Aquí lo que te haga falta de código
        $query_sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT pos.i_titulo AS Titulo,
                             pos.i_descripcion AS Descripcion,
                             pro.p_producto AS Producto,
                             usu.r_usuario AS Usuario
                      FROM   tb_post pos
                      INNER JOIN tb_publicacion pub ON
                      pos.id_publicacion = pub.id_publicacion
                      INNER JOIN tb_producto pro ON
                      pub.id_producto = pro.id_producto
                      INNER JOIN tb_usuario usu ON
                      pub.id_usuario = usu.id_usuario");

        while($renglon = mysqli_fetch_array($query_sql))
        {
            echo "<p>".$renglon["Titulo"]."</p>";
        }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### El problema está en el bucle y la variable `$titulo`:

Observe el siguiente fragmento de código, que es el que nos interesa:

```php
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_sql)) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($row);   
   $titulo = $row["Titulo"];
 }
}
```

**En el bucle anterior se observa que:**

```php
# Las siguientes instrucciones no son necesarias
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
```

Y la variable `$titulo` se inicializa en cada iteración del bucle, sustituyendo el valor obtenido en la iteración anterior. Esto da como resultado que el valor de la última iteración del bucle quede almacenado en la variable en lugar de todos los datos.

**Una posible solución sería:**

```php
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_sql)) {
 # Inicializar la variable $titulo:
 $titulo = "";
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
  # Añadir un operador de concatenación antes de "=": 
  $titulo .= ", " . $row["Titulo"];
 }
}
```